# Understanding FFMPEG codification process

Tags: ffmpeg

I am developing some code with **FFMPEG** and my purpose is to transcode a single video file with keykrame aligned to do **Adaptative Bitrate**.

So, my question are why fps is changing during codification process? 
Why fps number is not consecutive?

The ffmpeg script:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $INPUT_VIDEO -strict -2 -c:a aac -ac 1 -ab 128k -c:v libx264 -preset:v veryfast -threads 0 -r 24 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -x264opts no-mbtree:bframes=1 -pass 1 -b:v $BITRATE1 -s $RESOLUTION1 $OUTPUT_VIDEO1.mp4
```

The codification process:

ffmpeg screenshot
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The FPS is the files processed per second, not the frames per second of the resulting output.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton which are those file? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton you said FPS is files per second, what files exactly? Thank

Comment: Ah. I meant 'frames processed per second'. Sorry. The key point is 'processed' vs 'per'.

Answer (score 4):

The FPS is the frames *processed* per second. Not the FPS of the resulting movie but rather speed of encoding. Try doing something on your box and see it drop as CPU is used for some other tasks.